# Java won't recognize file in JAR

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a .csv database file inside my java program's JAR file. The program works fine in NetBeans IDE before I package it, but once I do, it refuses to believe the file is in it, even though I had it print out the path where it was looking and unzipped the JAR to be sure I told it to look in the right place. How do I make Java see this?

```
  try
  {
    String path = Main.class.getResource("/items.csv").getPath();
    db = new java.io.File(path);
    loadValues(db);
  }
  catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex1)
  {
    System.out.println("Could not find database file (" + ui.db + ").");
  }
```

Comment: Can you use stream instead of file name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't create a `File` object for the resource, as there may be no `File`. A `File` represents *only* "real" files on the filesystem. As far as the OS is concerned a "file" inside a .jar file is just some bytes.

You'll need to use [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get an `InputStream` and read from that.

Comment: then why does `java.awt.Image appImage32 = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Main.class.getResource("/mcitemcosts/resources/BHMCGrass 32.png"));` work just fine?

Comment: @Supuhstar: `getResource()` returns an `URL`. If you look at that value you'll notice that it doesn't just reference a file, it's a `jar:` URL (referencing an entry within the .jar file). If you call `getResource()` and call `openStream()` on the resulting `URL` then that's pretty much equivalent to `getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Also, how can I read the strings contained within the file using an `InputStream`?

Comment: @Supuhstar: well, your `loadValues()` will eventually need to create a `FileInputStream` or a `FileReader` to read from the file. You simply need to replace that with the `InputStream` you pass in (possibly wrapped in an `InputStreamReader`).

Comment: I've been using `new java.util.Scanner(db);` and its `next` methods

Comment: Well, there's a `Scanner` constructor that takes a `File` and there's a constructor that takes an `InputStream`. The rest is for you to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Once you pack it in jar file it is no longer a direct file..

Try to read it with [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

```
InputStream input = getClass().getRessourceAsStream("/classpath/to/my/items.csv");
```

**Also See**

- [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Class.getResourceAsStream` to load the files inside the jar:

```
    InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/items.csv");
    loadValues(is);
```

Change your `loadValues` method to work on an `InputStream` rather than a `File`.